# Convergence of ${\large\int}_{-\infty}^\infty J_0(x)\,J_0(x+a)\,dx$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, special-functions, closed-form

Consider
$$I(a)={\int}_{-\infty}^\infty J_0(x)\,J_0(x+a)\,dx,$$
where $J_0(z)$ is the [Bessel Function of the $1^{st}$ kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) and $a>0$.

Does this integral converge for any values of $a$? If so, is there a closed form for it? Can we find a value of $a$ such that $I(a)=0$?

Comment: $$a=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\qquad\overset{?}=>\qquad\int_{-\infty}^\infty J_0(x-a)\cdot J_0(x+a)~dx~\overset{?}=~1.$$

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot reliably verify this conjecture because of very slow convergence of numerical integration (and significant error in the result). How did you come up with it?

Comment: I plotted the integrand's graphic for various values of the parameter *a*, and couldn't help but notice that it was centered for $a=0$, but shifted for other values. I logically assumed that this was due to its lack of symmetry, so I changed it to $J_0\bigg(x\pm\dfrac a2\bigg)$. Then, given its similarity with $\dfrac{\sin x}x$, I tried to guess the value of *a* for which the positive and negative parts cancel out each other's divergent tendencies. I also plotted the hyperbolae $y=\pm\dfrac1{2x}$ for visual aid, which implied that *a* had to be in between $\pm1$. $[\ldots]$

Comment: Since $\dfrac\pi2$ appears in the various integral formulae for this and other related functions, $\dfrac2\pi$ was a first obvious choice. But both visual and numerical verifications, by integrating on intervals of the form $(-10^n,+10^n)$ , seemed to infirm that. So, going out on a limb, I tried $a=\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}$ , which appeared to actually work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral converges only when $a$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$,
and does not seem to vanish even for those $a$.

For large $\left|z\right|$ it is known that
$$
J_0(z) = \sqrt{\frac2{\pi\left|z\right|}}
 \bigl(\cos (\left|z\right|-\frac\pi4) + O(1/\left|z\right|) \bigr).
$$
Therefore we have for large $x$ (either $x>0$ and $x<0$):
$$
J_0(x+\frac{a}{2}) \, J_0(x-\frac{a}{2})
 = \frac2{\pi\left|x\right|} 
\bigl(\cos (\left|x\right|-\frac\pi4+\frac{a}2)
  \cos (\left|x\right|-\frac\pi4-\frac{a}2)
 + O(1/\left|x\right|) \bigr)
 = \frac1{\pi\left|x\right|} 
\bigl(\cos (2\left|x\right|-\frac\pi2) + \cos a + O(1/\left|x\right|) \bigr).
$$
The integral thus converges *iff* $\cos a = 0$, as claimed.

Morally speaking, $I(a)$ should be the convolution of $J_0$ with itself
(since $J_0$ is an even function), so its Fourier transform should be
the square of the Fourier transform of $J_0$.  But $J_0(x)$ can be written
as a Fourier integral $\frac1\pi \int_{-1}^1 \cos xt \, {\rm d}t/\sqrt{1-t^2}$,
so we should have $I(a) = \frac2\pi \int_{-1}^1 \cos at \, {\rm d}t/(1-t^2)$,
and now the integrand blows up too quickly at $t = \pm 1$ for the
integral to converge $-$ unless $\cos at = 0$ vanishes there,
which recovers our criterion $\cos a = 0$.  In that case
numerical integration corroborates the formula; e.g. for $a = \pm \pi/2$
we should have $I(a) = \frac2\pi \int_{-1}^1 \cos \frac{\pi t}{2} {\rm d}t/(1-t^2)$,
and the integral is the Gibbs constant $\int_0^\pi \sin t \, {\rm d}t/t
= 1.851937\ldots$ (write $\frac2{1-t^2} = \frac1{1-t} + \frac1{1+t}$, etc.)
and indeed $I(a)$ is approximately $1.179$ which is $2/\pi$ times
this constant.  For larger odd multiples of $\pi/2$ we find that
$I(a)$ alternates in sign and approaches $\pm 1$,
which again would be consistent with the formula
$I(a) = \frac2\pi \int_{-1}^1 \cos at \, {\rm d}t/(1-t^2)$.

To prove this integral formula when $a$ is an odd multiple of $\pi/2$,
start by writing $J_0(x-a) + J_0(x+a) =
 \frac2{\pi}\int_{-1}^1 \cos xt \cos at \, {\rm d}t/\sqrt{1-t^2}$,
and apply Parseval's formula to the inner product of $J_0(x)$ with
$J_0(x-a) + J_0(x+a)$.

Comment: $O(1/|x|^{3/2})$.

Comment: Where do you want $O(1/|x|^{3/2})$ to go?

Comment: $$J_0(x+\frac{a}{2}) \, J_0(x-\frac{a}{2})
 = \frac2{\pi\left|x\right|} 
\bigl(\cos (\left|x\right|-\frac\pi4+\frac{a}2)
  \cos (\left|x\right|-\frac\pi4-\frac{a}2)
 + O(1/\left|x\right|^{3/2}) \bigr)
 = \frac1{\pi\left|x\right|} 
\bigl(\cos (2\left|x\right|-\frac\pi2) + \cos a + O(1/\left|x\right|^{3/2}) \bigr)$$. 
Sorry, my comment  was too short.

Answer (score 3):

I bet that the answers to the first and third question (about convergence and zeroes) are affirmative, since the function
$$ f(z) = \left(1-\frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{x^4}{64}\right)\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}(x)+\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi x}}\cos(x-\pi/4)\mathbb{1}_{[1,+\infty)}(x),$$
by following Abramowitz and Stegun, is a very good approximation for $J_0(x)$, but I do not think there is a nice closed-form expression for your integral.

Comment: Prudnikov-Brychkov-Marychev, Vol.2, formula 2.12.33.14 gives
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{J_{\mu}(x+b)J_{\nu}(x+c)}{(x+b)^{\mu}(x+c)^{\nu}}\,dx=
\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}\,\Gamma\left(\mu+\nu\right)}{\Gamma\left(\mu+\frac12\right) \Gamma \left(\nu+\frac12\right)}\left(b-c\right)^{\frac12-\mu-\nu}J_{\mu+\nu-\frac12}(b-c),$$ valid for $\Re(\mu+\nu)>0$, $b>c>0$.
Unfortunately it does not seem possible to transform this expression into something reasonable by taking an appropriate limit. However it strongly suggests that if the integral converges, a nice closed form should exist.

Comment: Doesn't the choices $b=\alpha,c=\nu=\mu=0$ set the question? The function $J_{-1/2}(z)$ is very well-known!

Comment: No, I added the bounds. The problem is the pole of the gamma function $\Gamma(\mu+\nu)$.

Comment: Some careful choice of $(b,c,\mu,\nu)$ may allow one to take the limit properly, but it seems quite delicate.